# select query gives strange characters as output

Tags: android, sqlite, select, select-query

I have a problem when executing select query in android with sqlite database. In database there is a field based on sinhala characters. I populate the database using DB browser in UTF-8 encoding. I used SQLiteAssetHelper to access database in assets folder. when i try to use select query and display in android textview the data in field based on sinhala outputs strange characters like à·€à·’à¶¯à·Šâ€.

I try to change the font in textview and try to change the encoding by using `System.setProperty( sinhala_word,"UTF-8" )`.
As example when try to set word

> රහිත

in android text view it shows like

> à¶»à·„à·’à¶­

this is how my database looks like:
[image: this is how my database looks like]

This is how text appears in text view:
[image: This is how text appears in text view]